# Can I add a script to a Google Sheet using another script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script populate() to run an automation script on Google Sheets. I want this script to be run on over a hundred Google Sheets files. Is there a way to write a script to add to (or at least run) my populate() script on all those files? I prefer to be able to add the script to each file because we may need to run the scripts multiple times for each file. Otherwise, I will have to manually copy/paste the script to each sheet, which takes time.

Update: Removed the part about converting Excel files to Google Sheets because I found the answer for that on another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56063156/script-to-convert-xlsx-to-google-sheet-and-move-converted-file/56073634#56073634).

Comment: Write a script compatible with google to open each file in the folder, apply your script and dave. Run it, drink coffee and wait to finish.

Comment: I think that the question title doesn't match the question body. What does `populate()`? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: [SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))...[Folder.getFilesByType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByType(String))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood from your post, your question is about how to convert a series of Excel files inside a Drive folder into Google Sheets to then execute a function in them.

For that, you could iterate over all the files of your folder and convert them with the use of `Drive.insert` from the Drive API. For that, you will have to enable in your script the **Advanced Google Services**. If you do not know how to do so, please follow [these indications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

The following script performs what I think you are aiming for, it has self explanatory comments:

```
function convertExcelToGoogleSheets() {
  
  // Id of the folder where you have all your excel files
  var folderId = 'FOLDERID';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
  // Get all the files in your folder and iterate over them
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  // For each file:
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    
    // Get its blob (content)
    var blob = file.getBlob();
    
    // Create the resource to insert the Google Sheet file. Put the same name
    // as the original and set the type of the file to Google sheets and its 
    // parent folder to where the excel files are located
    var resource = {
      title: file.getName(),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
      parents: [{id: folderId}],
    };
    // User Drive API to insert the actual file and get its ID
    var id = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob).getId();
    // Whatever function you want to perform in the newly created Google Sheet
    // pasing the parameter of the file id
    myScript(id);  
    }
}

// Set the first cell of all the converted sheets to "IT WORKED"
function myScript(id){
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('IT WORKED!');
}
```

### Edit

If you want to run a script for each of this converted sheets you can simply call it in the `while` loop and pass the new file id as a parameter to then be able to use the script *(remember to encapsulate this script in a function)*.

Comment: Thanks Mateo. This solves the first problem of converting them to Google Sheets. However, my main problem is to be able to add that script to each file, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly for satisfying your question. Let me know if you have any doubts about it. :D