# Converting excel file to google sheet using Appscript keeps throwing Drive API Error "File Not Found"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am working on an appscript that downloads an excel attachment from my inbox into folder A, then converts it into a google sheet and is saved in the same folder A. I have used the guidance of a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56063156/script-to-convert-xlsx-to-google-sheet-and-move-converted-file) that utilizes Drive API services but keep receiving the following error on the last line "API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: File not found: WIP"

I have enabled "supportsAllDrives" and tried saving in different folders with no luck. Please view code below

```
function save_new_WIP() {

  //Looks for email attachment
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox subject:"WIP Update" to: "xxxxxxxxx"');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[0];

 

  //saves excel file in drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1uFvXhIIst_ksjZysyH-09TYeo5k44YvO");
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var newWIP = folder.createFile(attachment).setName(fileName);
  
  var ID = newWIP.getId();
  
 
  //converts xlxs excel file to google sheet.

  const excel = DriveApp.getFileById(ID);
  let file = {
    title: 'converted',
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{id: folder}],
    supportsAllDrives: true 
  };

  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, excel);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, it seems that `folder` of `parents: [{id: folder}],` is `var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1uFvXhIIst_ksjZysyH-09TYeo5k44YvO");`. In this case, `folder` is the Class Folder object. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let file = {
  title: 'converted',
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{id: folder}],
  supportsAllDrives: true 
};
```

#### To:

```
let file = {
  title: 'converted',
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{ id: folder.getId() }], // Modified
  supportsAllDrives: true 
};
```

#### Note:

When your whole script is modified, it becomes as follows. In this case, the folder ID is declared as `folderId`.

```js
function save_new_WIP() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox subject:"WIP Update" to: "xxxxxxxxx"');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[0];
  var folderId = "1uFvXhIIst_ksjZysyH-09TYeo5k44YvO";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var newWIP = folder.createFile(attachment).setName(fileName);
  var ID = newWIP.getId();
  const excel = DriveApp.getFileById(ID);
  let file = {
    title: 'converted',
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
    parents: [{ id: folderId }],
    supportsAllDrives: true
  };
  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, excel);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getId() of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getid)