# Copy data from excel sheet to gsheet (both located on gDrive)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have file on gsheet in `xlsx` format.

[image]

This file is updated each month by adding new version of file.
I have second file (it's a gsheet) where I want to add some graphic based on data from first file.

My first approach was gsheet function `IMPORTRANGE`
But it doesn't work with file format `xlsx`.
[image]
Second approach was to create gscript with some scheduler for synchronization

```
function synchronizujDaneZExcela() {
  // Ustawienia
  var kluczPlikuExcela = "_____MY_KEY_____";
  
  // Ustawienia
  var nazwaArkuszaExcela = "Podsumowanie"; // Nazwa zakładki w pliku Excela
  var nazwaArkuszaGoogle = "Podsumowanie kopia"; // Nazwa zakładki w arkuszu Google Sheets
  
  // Pobierz plik Excela
  var plik = DriveApp.getFileById(kluczPlikuExcela);
  
  // Jeśli plik Excela został znaleziony
  if (plik) {
    // Pobierz dane z arkusza "Podsumowanie" w pliku Excela
    var excelData = SpreadsheetApp.open(plik).getSheetByName(nazwaArkuszaExcela).getDataRange().getValues();
    
    
    // Otwórz arkusz Google Sheets
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    
    // Sprawdź, czy arkusz "Podsumowanie kopia" istnieje, jeśli nie, stwórz nowy
    var arkusz = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(nazwaArkuszaGoogle);
    if (!arkusz) {
      arkusz = spreadsheet.insertSheet();
      arkusz.setName(nazwaArkuszaGoogle);
    }
    
    // Wstaw dane do arkusza Google Sheets
    arkusz.clear(); // Wyczyść arkusz "Podsumowanie kopia"
    arkusz.getRange(1, 1, excelData.length, excelData[0].length).setValues(excelData);
    
    Logger.log("Synchronizacja zakończona pomyślnie.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("Plik Excela nie został znaleziony.");
  }
}
```

But I'm also getting error
`Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id ....`

Do you have idea for some idea or other approach for this case?

Comment: Only idea I can think of is to convert the .xslx file to Google Sheets then import the data from the converted file. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56063156/script-to-convert-xlsx-to-google-sheet-and-move-converted-file) might help with the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy values from XLSX to Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.
- There are both the XLSX file and a Google Spreadsheet on your Google Drive.

Recently, Microsoft Docs files (Word, Excel, and PowerPoint files) could be manually edited by opening them on Google Drive using the browser. But, in the current stage, unfortunately, those Microsoft Docs files cannot be directly used with Google Apps Script. For example, XLSX files cannot be used with Google Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and Sheets API. But, when XLSX file can be used with Spreadsheet service, it will be useful.

As the current workaround, in order to use the XLSX file with SpreadsheetApp, it is required to convert XLSX to Google Spreadsheet. This has already been mentioned in the comments. So, I created a Google Apps Script library to achieve this simply. In this answer, I would like to propose a sample script for achieving the above goal using the library.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install library

Please install a Google Apps Script library `MicrosoftDocsApp`. You can see how to install it [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/MicrosoftDocsApp?tab=readme-ov-file#1-install-library).

This library uses Drive API v3. If an error is related to Drive API, please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services.

#### 2. Sample script

In this case, the script is used with the target Google Spreadsheet. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of your Google Spreadsheet. And, please set the file ID of the XLSX file and the destination sheet name of the active Spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const fileIdOfXLSX = "###"; // Please set the file ID of your XLSX file on your Google Drive.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your target sheet name you want to put the values from XLSX file.

  // Retrieve values from XLSX file.
  const MD = MicrosoftDocsApp.setFileId(fileIdOfXLSX);
  const srcSS = MD.getSpreadsheet();
  const values = srcSS.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(values); // Confirm the retrieved values in the log.

  // Put values to the target sheet.
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  MD.end(); // When this line is run, the Spreadsheet created as a temporal file from the XLSX file is removed.

  // SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This comment line is used for automatically detecting a scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets" by the script editor. So, please don't remove this comment line.
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of the 1st sheet of the XLSX file are put into "Sheet1".

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### Reference:

- [MicrosoftDocsApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/MicrosoftDocsApp)

Answer (score 1):

Do recommend SheetGo (3rd party solution). It's a good approach to handle this task efficiently. Here's how you can use SheetGo to achieve this:

1. Install SheetGo:
   Go to the GSuite Marketplace and install [SheetGo](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/sheetgo/94172092257). SheetGo allows you to connect and automate data flows between Google Sheets, Excel files, and other cloud applications.
2. Connect your Excel file and Google Sheets file:
   Open the app and connect both your Excel file and your Google Sheets file.
   Follow the prompts to authorize access to your Google Drive and select the Excel file you want to connect.
3. Set up the data flow:
   Once your files are connected, you can set up the data flow to transfer data from the Excel file to your Google Sheets file.
   You can specify which sheets or ranges you want to transfer data from, and where you want the data to be placed in your Google Sheets file.
4. Schedule the synchronization:
   SheetGo allows you to schedule automatic data synchronization at regular intervals. Set up a schedule that suits your needs, whether it's daily, weekly, or monthly, to ensure that your Google Sheets file stays up to date with the latest data from your Excel file.

Using SheetGo simplifies the process of synchronizing data between Excel and Google Sheets, eliminating the need for manual scripts and troubleshooting issues with accessing files.