Google Apps Script: 'Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document' error when trying to open Google Sheets by ID
Can you please help me troubleshoot what is incorrect in the below code? (this is code to fetch information from a spreadsheet and populate a Slides template with the Spreadsheet into, then output it into another G Drive folder).
Whenever I try to run it I get an error. All the files and folder are in the G Drive of the same account that is logged in on Apps Scrips...so I'm not sure what's causing the issue...the error code is:
Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id ' '
Here's the code below (with the doc and folder IDs removed):
function createCertificates() {
  // Open the specific Google Sheets spreadsheet by its ID
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Open the Google Slides certificate template by its ID
  const slideTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('');
  
  // Define the folder where the generated certificates will be saved
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('');
  
  // Get all values from column C, starting from row 2 to exclude headers
  const data = sheet.getRange('C2:C' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // Iterate over each row and generate certificates
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const [fullName] = data[i];
    
    // Skip empty rows
    if (!fullName) continue;
    
    // Make a copy of the certificate template
    const copy = slideTemplate.makeCopy(`${fullName} Certificate`, folder);
    
    // Open the copied Google Slide and replace the placeholder with the full name
    const slides = SlidesApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const slide = slides.getSlides()[0];
    slide.replaceAllText('{{FullName}}', fullName);
    slides.saveAndClose();
  }
}

Your help is greatly appreciated!!!
Regards
Dee

Approved the permission prompts that appeared on my phone and via email
Tried to create a new file with the same code, but same issue
Tried to refresh screen, and use different browser (Brave browser)

13 Nov 2024 Update
We've been tinkering with the code, here's an updated version that is doing 98% of what we want it to:

The code is working
The certificate is being generated and downloaded
The email is being generated
I'm receiving the test emails with the generated certificate

The only piece that's not working is the content of the certificate itself, as in the certificate being generated doesn't have the {{FullName}} replaced with the relevant Fullname.
We've been trying several versions of the code, but still see the same result; the generated certificate doesn't have the text in the relevant box replaced with the user's name.
Here's the updated code below (IDs of files removed):
function generateAndSendCertificates() {
  
  const spreadsheetId = 'SPREADSHEET_ID';
  const templateId = 'SLIDES_TEMPLATE_ID';

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/; // Simple regex for email validation

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const name = data[i][2];  // Column C (FullName)
    const email = data[i][3]; // Column D (Email)

    if (!name || !email || !emailRegex.test(email)) {
      console.warn(`Skipping row ${i + 1} due to invalid or missing name/email: ${name}, ${email}`);
      continue;
    }

    const copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy(`${name} Certificate`).getId();
    const copy = SlidesApp.openById(copyId);

    const slides = copy.getSlides();
    slides.forEach(slide => {
      slide.getPageElements().forEach(element => {
        if (element.getPageElementType() == SlidesApp.PageElementType.TEXT_BOX) {
          const textRange = element.asTextBox().getText();
          const fullText = textRange.asString();
          
          // Check if the placeholder exists in the text box
          if (fullText.includes('{{FullName}}')) {
            // Replace {{FullName}} with the actual name
            textRange.replaceAllText('{{FullName}}', name);
          }
        }
      });
    });

    copy.saveAndClose();

    const pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf');

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Your Certificate', 'Please find your certificate attached.', {
      attachments: [pdf],
      name: 'Certificate Bot'
    });

    DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById('YOUR_FOLDER_ID'));
  }
}


Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, about your error Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id, your situation might be related to this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78187221

One reason could be that there are a lot of people accessing the associated files.

Thanks @Tanaike, I checked out the response and looked at that SheetGo extension. I don't think that'll work for me, looks like SheetGo doesn't work with Google Slides...but thank you so much for the response!

Thanks @4thAnd1, I'm the only one accessing the file, but I'll try again periodically, in case something different pops up in the logs

This might be a problem that only Google can help to solved. Yo should look to the Google Apps Script issue tracker for similar reporta.

Thank you for replying. I apologize for my comment not being useful. About your current situation, for example, in order to confirm your script for correctly replicating your issue, can you provide a sample file of the file ID of SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getSheetByName('Sheet1');?

You can also try to check if the permission of the associates files is set to  "Anyone with the link can edit"

This seems to be a widespread issue you may try visiting this thread on Issue Tracker for some insights.

Thanks so much for the continued input everyone!
I've added an update to the question, with the updated code are testing at the moment, the issues we're having with it and how it's working (we're almost there!)

The only piece that's not working is You are asking users to troubleshoot code without knowing the content of the files. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and then edit the question to include a spreadsheet (containing sample data) and a slides template , as well as an example of success outcome.
